# Gitlab shared runners + liquibase

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, gitlab-ci, liquibase, gitlab-ci-runner

I would like to setup a Gitlab pipeline that uses liquibase to execute a database migration. I am using Gitlab shared runners to execute the pipeline.

I would like to do this while keeping my database behind an SSH bastion so no direct connection is allowed.

I have seen most people follow these approaches to accomplish this:

- Use specific runners instead of shared ones
- Deploy an instance in ECS that contains the migration script

Is there any best practice or solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Can you make a jdbc url that connects the database if so Liquibase can establish the connection.
Here are the common ways to form a [jdbc url](https://www.codejava.net/java-se/jdbc/jdbc-database-connection-url-for-common-databases).
Once you have that url, you can put it in the [liquibase.properties](https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/creating-config-properties.html) file to connect to the database

Comment: This would not fulfill the requirement to have the database behind an SSH bastion. JDBC URL is not the issue I'm having.